# Is it possible to use Cloud NAT with public GKE Cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nat

I have one public GKE cluster with 2 nodes and with that, 2 public external IPs. I want only one egress IP.

I want to use Cloud NAT for that. It seems it is possible.

> An alias IP range assigned to the VM's network interface: Even if the
>   network interface has an external IP address assigned to it, you can
>   configure a Cloud NAT gateway to provide NAT for packets whose sources
>   come from an alias IP range of the interface. An external IP address
>   on an interface never performs one-to-one NAT for alias IP addresses.

I created a Cloud NAT but it is not working. I use the following commands to get the IP and it always returns one of the IPs of the nodes.

```
kubectl run -i --tty get-ip-address --image=dwdraju/alpine-curl-jq --restart=Never
```

and

```
curl checkip.amazonaws.com
```

My cluster has VPC native enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Private [Kubernetes Cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept) option. The nodes will only have internal IP addresses.

If you follow this [guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-cloud-nat-with-gke-cluster-c82364546d9e), you will be able to achieve your desired configuration using Private clusters.

Comment: But I also want public endpoints for my REST API. Will a private cluster work?

Comment: If you use the curl command. the Cloud NAT public IP will server as the public endpoint.

For example, using the command "curl checkip.amazonaws.com" will output the public IP address assigned when you created your NAT gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud NAT does not work with public clusters. However, this just means that your nodes will not have public IPs. Private clusters can still use public endpoints by using service type LoadBalancer or using ingress resources.

For your endpoint REST API endpoint, use either an ingress or loadbalancer with a static IP to make sure the endpoint is reachable from outside the cluster and the endpoint (IP or URL) is stable.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to still use Cloud NAT even with a public GKE cluster by deploying `IP-MASQ` agents on each node that overwrites Node's NAT iptables and bypasses `Masquerade` for internal traffic

https://rajathithanrajasekar.medium.com/google-cloud-public-gke-cluster-egress-traffic-via-static-ip-addresses-for-ip-whitelisting-1cb024228e7e